# Add new column to table or join new table

Tags: mysql

I have a table with a couple million records that I need to add columns to.

In an effort to mitigate any risk/downtime I am contemplating just creating another table with the primary key and new column and using a left join to add the new data.

Will there be any difference in performance between using a join and or having the data within the same table?

Comment: Test it and you will see. Probably there will be as you have to make joins to get the same data. Whether the overhead is acceptable to you, you can determine by testing.

Comment: 2M rows with SSD disk won't take long to add columns to, even in old versions of MySQL.  A billion rows or HDD is another story.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, there will be a performance difference if you have to join to get a column versus the column being part of the pages you already read from the primary table. Join performance can be partly mitigated by defining the right indexes, but it will still be somewhat different performance. Since you haven't described your table, I can't suggest specific indexes.

There are at least two ways to solve the problem that led you to this question:

- Use MySQL 8.0.12 or later, which supports [instant add column](https://dev.mysql.com/blog-archive/mysql-8-0-innodb-now-supports-instant-add-column/).
- Use an online schema change tool such as [pt-online-schema-change](https://docs.percona.com/percona-toolkit/pt-online-schema-change.html) or [gh-ost](https://github.com/github/gh-ost). At my last job, we used the former tool, and we ran hundreds of schema changes of all types against production tables during peak traffic without suffering downtime.